# VSCode theming apply styles to all childs

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

In vscode theming is it possible to apply a style to all childs of a group?
For example in php exists a selector for `support.function.array.php` and `support.function.file.php`.

I thought that the styles of `support.function.php` would be applied to both childs, but unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer

`source.php support.function`

EDIT:

With `source.php` the selector is restricted to php only.

With `support.function` I can select all support functions.

My previous approach `support.function.php` isn't supported in this way.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? Why is this the answer to your original problem. This way others will benefit and learn from your answer.